# Magento Wishlist Grouped Products with 0 quantity

Tags: magento-enterprise, grouped-products, wishlist

Ok, so i have grouped product pages that show the different individual items all with text fields that start off with having 0 displayed in them.

(please understand that changing this to a drop down is not an option)

The issue i have here, is that with a grouped product page that has for example 10 products, if on 1 line i change quantity to 1 and leave rest 0, then click add to wishlist, on the wishlist page it will show every line including the ones with 0 quantity, which starts to look really bad.

I am sure its possible, but i have spent a long time trying to figure this one out.

How would i go about either hiding those lines from the wishlist page, or maybe looping through and not processing the ones that equal 0.

app\design\frontend\enterprise\My_Theme\template\wishlist\options_list.phtml is where it cycles through to put the information down

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your input. You could be on to something.

After a little digging around looking into the functions that get called. i extended this file app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist.php and around line 355 you can see the following snippet

```
$cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->processConfiguration($_buyRequest, $product);
```

i changed that to the following to ensure the processmode is set as FULL rather than LITE

```
$cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->prepareForCartAdvanced($_buyRequest, $product);
```

This meant that it would validate against adding a grouped product to cart when no quantity is added, and also add the individual grouped products as simple products to the wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simpler solution might be to add the grouped product that you wanted as a simple product.